# Tailwind styles broken on deployment and WSL

Tags: next.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, daisyui, tailwind-css

While using Next.js + Tailwind + DaisyUI in development on Mac everything works as expected and all styles look normal, however when developing on WSL I noticed that my styles look very different and are pretty much broken from what I would expect. I'm encountering this same issue when deploying my site to Vercel. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Development (Mac)
[image]

Deployment (Vercel)
[image]

tailwind.config.js

[image]

I attempted to recreate the issue on my mac with no luck, however it seems this issue is showing up on Linux and Vercel deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Turns out the issue stemmed from the fact that I had a css file in my styles folder and when I imported it into my homepage, it messed up the styling for everything else.

Not sure if this is supposed to be the expected behavior, but it did solve the issue